# Disable admin user category Drag and Drop for Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, category-products, php-7.2

I am looking into if it is indeed possible to disable the ability for a user to drag / move and drop categories in the Magento2 admin panel.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this on per user basis or just a global disable for all users would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via overwriting core module code via your custom module.

Create the **di.xml** in following Path **{Vendor_Module}/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

Add the below code in it.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree" 
    type="Grazitti\Minicart\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree"/>
</config>
```

Then Override the **Tree.php** file
**{Vendor_Module}\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree.php**

Then in your find the below function

```
 protected function _getNodeJson($node, $level = 0)
```

Find below line in this function

```
$item['allowDrag'] = $allowMove && ($node->getLevel() == 1 && $rootForStores ? false : true);
```

Replace with

```
$item['allowDrag'] = $allowMove && ($node->getLevel() == 1 && $rootForStores ? false : false);
```

Comment: Ah that looks promising and make sense. I will try this out over the coming weekend and provide feedback.